# click trigger() not working when page loads

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to make a trigger work based on the query string of the URL
I use this code to get URL string

```js
var getUrlParameter = function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
  var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1),
    sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
    sParameterName,
    i;

  for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
    sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');

    if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
      return sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : decodeURIComponent(sParameterName[1]);
    }
  }
};
```

and once I get it I put it inside an if then else like so:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  let code_para = getUrlParameter("code");

  if (code_para == "one") {
    $("#one").trigger('click');
  } else if(code_para == "two") {
    $("#two").trigger('click');
  } else if(code_para == "three") {
    $("#three").trigger('click');
  } else if(code_para == "four") {
    $("#four").trigger('click');
  } else if(code_para == "five") {
    $("#five").trigger('click');
  } else {
    //do nothing
  }
});
```

but the problem is the trigger part is not working I have attached a fiddle for the full code
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7g3qnbhw/)

Comment: Did you add a `console.log(code_para);` to see what the value of code_para is?

Comment: yes i get the correct values

Comment: If the fiddle is like your actual code, then you are adding the click handler `$(document).on('click','.container_courses'` after you call `getUrlParameter("code");` and trigger the event. Have you tried moving your code to trigger the click to the end of your list of document.readys? I needs to be triggered after the click handler is assigned.

Comment: @BenjaminHutchinson can you add little more explanation what you are trying to achieve has I don't see any event which have been binded to specified ids elements.

Comment: You have multiple document ready blocks and you are trying to trigger a click before the click event is registered. I suggest to have one document ready block and declare all the hover and click handlers in the beginning and then have a check for code_para and trigger the clicks.

Comment: Please ensure *all* relevant code is in the question.  Your code *in the question* does not have click events to trigger.  See [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that clicking on `#three` (for example) does nothing (based on the provided fiddle).

So triggering the click, does nothing.

It's not (just) that it's too early, because the other bindings (`hover` and `click`) are on `.box3`, not `#three`.  You need to trigger on `.box3`, eg:

```
$(()=> $(".box3").trigger('mouseover').trigger("click") )
```

So your (`switch`) would need to convert:

```
if (code_para == "one") {
    $(".box1").trigger('mouseover').trigger("click")
```

Comment: thank you this worked

Answer (score 0):

couple of suggestions - you could simplify your logic and simply use the code_para as the identifier on the selector (assuming that the code_para is actually the same as the id of the element you want to click. Not the else block remains to do something in the avbsence of code_para).

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        let code_para = getUrlParameter("code");
       if (code_para)
       {
           $("#" + code_para).trigger('click');
       } else {
           //do nothing
       }
    });
```

But rather than triggering a click on another DOM element - I would trigger the function that the click causes - so if these items have a function on the click - then i would simply trigger the function directly - rather than stimulating  a click event that then triggers the fucntion....